# Does anyone install zoom conferencing client on Raspberry PI?

Tags: client, zoom-meeting

I am attempting to run Zoom conference client on Raspberry PI 3. But having no success. Have anyone tried to run zoom.us client on Raspberry PI? If you do please share.

Comment: Is the pi running Raspbian, or Ubuntu? If Ubuntu, which version?

Comment: I'm temped to close this question as it does not appear to be about Ubuntu.  If it is what version do you have installed?